# One spreadsheet for each user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, global-variables, spreadsheet

I have a code in GAS that works with a spreadsheet at the background and it works for a single use simultaneously.
The problem is that I want to create a copy of the spreadsheet, at the beginning of the code, for the interaction with every user that enter at the web App.
I tried two possibilities:

- Create the duplicate at the beginning of the main.js in order to be recognized as global variable for every function in the code, but the code creates repetitive files when I interact with any element at the web page because Javascript read the codes with every interaction.
- Create the duplicate within DoGet function creating at the end a variable linked to the Id or to the new file, but the rest of functions don't recognized that variable like a global variable, even declaring the variable at the beginning of the main.js

Code

```
var x;
if(x == null){
    var myArray  = crearnuevoarchivo(x);
    x = myArray[0];
    var database = myArray[1];
}     

const sheetConfiguracion = database.getSheetByName("Configuracion");
var lastRowProgramas = lastRowForColumn(sheetConfiguracion, 18);
var lastRowMandos = lastRowForColumn(sheetConfiguracion, 12);
const sheetTipos = database.getSheetByName("Tipos");
var lastRowTipos = sheetTipos.getLastRow();
const sheetSolicitud = database.getSheetByName("Solicitud");
const registro_peticiones = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');  
const sheetRegistro = registro_peticiones.getSheetByName("Registro");
const sheetHerramientas = database.getSheetByName("Herramientas");
var lastRowHerramientas = lastRowForColumn(sheetHerramientas, 1);
const sheetSolicitudFOD = database.getSheetByName("Solicitud_FOD");
const sheetfotosID = database.getSheetByName("FotosID"); 


function crearnuevoarchivo(x){
  if(x == null){
   const database2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var hoyarchivo = new Date();
  var mesarchivo = hoyarchivo.getMonth() + 1;
  var fechaarchivo = mesarchivo+"/"+hoyarchivo.getFullYear();
  const databaseID = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxx').makeCopy('database '+fechaarchivo, DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxx')).getId(); 
  var database = SpreadsheetApp.openById(databaseID);
  x = 1;
  var myArray = new Array(2);
      myArray[0] = x;
      myArray[1] = database;
  return myArray
  }
}
  
var rutaWeb = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

function doGet(e) {
if(e.parameter.p){
var page = e.parameter.p;
        if(page == "noFOD"){  
           var hojas = database.getSheets();
           var nuevaSheet = hojas.pop();
           var valor = nuevaSheet.getRange(2, 14).getValue();
           return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate();
        }
        else{
        if(page == "catalogo"){
               var hojas = database.getSheets();
               var nuevaSheet = hojas.pop();
               nuevaSheet.getRange(3, 14).setValue(1);
               var valor = nuevaSheet.getRange(3, 14).getValue();
               return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate();
            }
        if(page == "index"){
                    var hojas = database.getSheets();
                    var nuevaSheet = hojas.pop();
                    var valor = nuevaSheet.getRange(5, 14).getValue();
                    var r = 5;
                    borrar_registro_noFOD();
                    borrar_registro_FOD()
                    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate();
                    }
        if(page == "FOD"){  
                        var hojas = database.getSheets();
                        var nuevaSheet = hojas.pop();
                        var valor = nuevaSheet.getRange(4, 14).getValue();
                        var r = 4;
                        return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate();
                        }
        if(page == "catalogoFOD"){ 
                        var hojas = database.getSheets();
                        var nuevaSheet = hojas.pop();
                        var r = 6;
                        nuevaSheet.getRange(6, 14).setValue(r)
                        return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate();
                        }
        }
  }else{
    var out = new Array()
    
    var sheets = database.getSheets();
    for (var i=12 ; i < sheets.length ; i++){ 
    var sheet= database.getSheetByName(sheets[i].getName());
    database.deleteSheet(sheet);
    }
    const sheetTipos = database.getSheetByName("Tipos");
    sheetTipos.copyTo(database);
    var hojas = database.getSheets();
    var nuevaSheet = hojas.pop();
    nuevaSheet.getRange(2, 14).setValue(0);
    nuevaSheet.getRange(3, 14).setValue(0);
    nuevaSheet.getRange(4, 14).setValue(0);
    nuevaSheet.getRange(5, 14).setValue(0);
    nuevaSheet.getRange(1, 14, 7, 1).clearContent();
    nuevaSheet.getRange(2, 14, 6, 1).setValue(0);
    nuevaSheet.getRange(1, 15, 100, 7).clearContent();
    borrar_registro_noFOD(database);
    borrar_registro_FOD(database)
    var x = 1;
    var page = "index";
    }
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate();
}
```

Example of parameters that I'm passing from Index.html

```
/* <a href="<?!= rutaWeb + '?p=noFOD' ?>"  */
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Moreover, can you share the code you are using?

Comment: My question is how I could create a copy of one spreadsheet, with the script, and get that all functions understand it as global variable. I declare it at the beginning of the main.js but it creates continuous spreadsheets with any interaction.

Comment: So basically you want to execute all the functions for each copy of the main spreadsheet you are creating?

Comment: Yes. Create a specific copy for each running of the code  and use the variable object spreadsheet as global variable

Answer (score 0):

Global variables in Apps Script are different from global variables in other programming languages.

A way of storing *global* variables is making use of the `PropertiesService` class in Apps Script and using:

- `setProperty(key, value)` - for storing the key-value pair;
- `getProperty(key)` - for retrieving the value associated with the key.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Properties Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties).